# use of updated weights in tensorflow

Tags: tensorflow, linear-regression

I have tried a sample example in tensorflow. My question is when I run y_pred with the same initial features x, does it use weights updated in the preceding for loop or it just uses the initialized weights.

```
#linear regression for y = -(x-1)
x = tf.placeholder(dtype=tf.float32,shape=(None,1))
y_true = tf.placeholder(dtype=tf.float32,shape=(None,1))

linear_model = tf.layers.Dense(units=1)
y_pred = linear_model(x)

sess = tf.Session()
init = tf.global_variables_initializer()
sess.run(init)

loss = tf.losses.mean_squared_error(labels = y_true,predictions=y_pred)
optimizer = tf.train.GradientDescentOptimizer(learning_rate=0.01)
train = optimizer.minimize(loss)
for i in range(1000):
    _,loss_ = sess.run((train,loss),{x:[[0],[1],[2],[3]],y_true:[[1],[0],[-1],[-2]]})

print(sess.run(y_pred,{x:[[0],[1],[2],[3]]}))
```

My confusion arises from the documentation when it says that, to calculate the output of an operation it backtracks. So, to calculate y_pred, it backtracks and initialize the weights and calculate y_pred using x? or does it use already updated weights of the Dense layer?

The output of the above code is:

```
[[ 0.9960759 ]
 [-0.00208616]
 [-1.0002482 ]
 [-1.9984105 ]]
```

Answer (score 0):

"The documentation says that to calculate the output of an operation it backtracks" -> this means that your pick a node (in your case `y_pred`) and you follow the dependency graph until you reach the end of it. There's no time concept in this backtracking operation, you're just resolving a path in a graph.

Hence, when you run `(train,loss)` you're even there using this backtrack algorithm to solve every required node for the correct and parallel evaluation of both nodes.
In particular, the `train` operation will resolve to a set of gradient computation and assign operations that will be executerd in order to correctly evaluate the `train` node.

The execution of the `assing` nodes will make the network parameters update.

Hence, you will update the network parameters exactly `1000` times.

At the end of the training loop you are going to evaluate `y_pred`. The evaluation of this node will backtrack to the required input nodes and it will use the updated parameters to compute the correct output.